# Octave x-value of a minimum y

Tags: octave, minimum

I am trying to discern what the x-value of my minimum y is in a simple function I input into octave. I have the minimum y, and I could go back and search for what x gave that y, but I'm trying to make it display the coordinates in one go. I'm certain there's in easy way to go about it, but I'm definitely missing something. Here's the function:

```
%W1
%function W=kopt(R,k);
R=3;
k=[0:0.001:3];
F=(-0.5*k.^2)+(k.^2-k-(R.^(-1))*(1+k.*R).*(e.^(-2*k.*R)).+k.*(k.-2).* 
(1+k.*R).*e.^(-k.*R))./(1+(e.^(-k.*R)).*(1+k*R+(k.^2)*(R.^2)/3));
W=F+1/R;
plot(k,W)
min(W)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

[`min`](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.3/Utility-Functions.html#XREFmin) can return the index of the minimum value:

```
> [minval, iminval] = min(W)
minval = -0.31700
iminval =  981
> k(iminval)
ans =  0.98000
```

So after `plot(k, W)`, you could do

```
[minval, iminval] = min(W);
hold()
plot(k(iminval), minval)
```